# Apply a click event to everything but a single element

Tags: javascript, html, events

I want to apply a click event to an entire page in Javascript, to everything but a single banner on top. Let's say that the banner that I don't want the event in has an id of 'bannerID'. I tried doing the following:

```
document.onclick = function(){clickEvent()}

document.getElementById("bannerID").onclick = function(){return false;}
```

However, it looks like the document event overrides everything. Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check for the element-id within the handler, something like;

```
document.onclick = clickEvent;

function clickEvent(e) {
 var from = e.target || e.srcElement;
 if (from.id === 'bannerID') { return; }
 /* ... the handling continues ... */
}
```

This is called [event delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)

Answer (score 2):

Pass in an `event` parameter to the callback and check if the id is 'bannerID'

```
document.onclick = 
    function(event){
        if(event.target.id != 'bannerID'){
            clickEvent()
        }
    };
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/skyerkkz/1/)

Answer (score 0):

In the code you have above, you are adding two click events to "bannerID" - so it will execute `clickEvent()` **and** return `false`.

You can, however, exclude the specific element from the `onclick` function. This might help:

```
document.onclick = function(e) {
  if (e.target.id === 'bannerID') {
    return false;
  } else {
    clickEvent();
  }
};
```